# What is the equivalent of netstat -tln on OS X?

Tags: command-line

What is the equivalent of Linux's `netstat -tln` on OS X?

Options:

```
-l, --listening (Show only listening sockets. (These are omitted by default.)
--numeric , -n (Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.)
-t, --tcp
```

Comment: What does `netstat -tln` actually do?

Comment: You can just open a Terminar an execute on it. It will work.

Comment: @jherran No, OS X is using a BSD-based netstat which accepts different sets of options.

Comment: @patrix in Linux, it lists all open TCP ports on the machine, and whether it listens locally (127.0.0.1) or to remote connections (0.0.0.0).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Should be this command:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP:$PORT -sTCP:LISTEN
```

[Who is listening on a given TCP port on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421674/1884961)

Comment: OP question didn't have a port argument, this answer requires one. This gives a useful command https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/327967/209603

Comment: @goetzc Just use `-iTCP` instead of `-iTCP:$PORT`.

Comment: I would add `-P` since OP specified `-n` in their question. Also +1 to @Navin. `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P` is closer to `netstat -tln`

Answer (score 27):

The closest equivalent you can get on macOS is:

```
netstat -p tcp -van | grep '^Proto\|LISTEN'
```

- `tu` options are not available, but they can be replaced by either `-p tcp` or `-p udp`, although you can't have both at the same time
- `-p` option is replaced  with `-v` which effectively gets you PIDs listed
- `-l` option is not available, but you can work around it by using `-a` option (which includes servers in the listing) and  `grep LISTEN` (to filter only for listening)

Answer (score 6):

For real-time monitoring, try this:

```
nettop -p 60683
```

You can also restrict the interface type, like wifi or wired...

```
nettop -t wifi -n -p 60683
```